# Tensorflow automatic mixed precision fp16 slower than fp32 on official resnet

Tags: tensorflow, half-precision-float

I am trying to use the official ResNet model benchmarks from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/resnet/estimator_benchmark.py#L191 to experiment with the AMP support included in `tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0rc0`. I'm running on a 2080 Ti, driver 410.78, CUDA 10, Ubuntu.

I have made the following changes to help make sure the comparisons are quick and apples-to-apples:

- Reduced epochs to 10.
- Removed the 2x larger batch size for the `tweaked` runs so that everything is training on the same number of samples.
- Set the checkpointing to only happen once, after training is finished.
- Switched training to use CIFAR-10, since I have that downloaded on local disk.

I see this in the logs, which implies to me that AMP is active:

```
2019-06-03 16:08:40.976829: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1767] Running auto_mixed_precision graph optimizer
2019-06-03 16:08:40.977057: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:40.985402: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:40.986858: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:40.987745: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:40.996781: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:41.001948: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:41.003208: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:41.004589: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:41.005981: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1241] No whitelist ops found, nothing to do
2019-06-03 16:08:41.511761: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1767] Running auto_mixed_precision graph optimizer
2019-06-03 16:08:41.527751: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/auto_mixed_precision.cc:1723] Converted 529/2910 nodes to float16 precision using 3 cast(s) to float16 (excluding Const and Variable casts)
```

But the actual runtime is slower:

[fp32 (cyan) runtime is less than all of the fp16 runs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYYro.png)

What can I do to see a performance improvement?